# How to order String based on the first letter of each word in string using SQL query

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by

I want to sort string based on first letter of word **T** in a string. 
At first all strings with starting letter **T** will display then those that start with **T** in words other than the first would appear in alphabetical order

**Input:**(Below are strings which contains word starting with T)
Catering Truck
Ice Cream Truck
Tank Hauler
Trade Contractor
Pizza Time

**Expected O/P after sorting**
Tanks Hauler
Trade Contractor
Catering Truck
Ice Cream Truck
Pizza Time

Comment: What did you try so far? What string functions did you use to find out that the strings contain the letter "T"?

Comment: I used Like operator to get string containing letter T ('T%' OR ' % T%')
In order by clause, I am trying to write case statement to filter out to get expected o/p.

Comment: please add the queries you used and the problem you ran into

Comment: ORDER BY some CASE expression etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from tableName
order by 
    case when columnName like 'T%' then 1 else 0 end, 
    columnName
```

Comment: select * 
from tableName
order by 
    case when columnName like 'T%' then 0 else 1 end, 
    columnName  

will work instead